# Python REST request to HTTPS server with SSLv3

Tags: python, ssl, curl, python-requests, tls1.2

I am trying to retrieve data from a URL however it my connections are being blocked due to this error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='securehost', port=4443): Max retries exceeded with url: secureURL (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')],)",),))
```

As of now I think I am receiving this error because they cannot agree on an SSL cipher to use.

The default SSL types in the requests library are:

```
TLS13-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS13-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:TLS13-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+CHACHA20:DH+AESGCM:DH+CHACHA20:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MD5
```

However when I run curl -v on the server I am attempting to request data from I get this:

```
$ curl -v SecureLink
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying 8.8.8.8...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to SecureLink (8.8.8.8) port 4443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / DES-CBC3-SHA
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; CN=secureDomain
*  start date: Sep  1 17:52:38 2016 GMT
*  expire date: Sep  1 17:52:38 2019 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "secureHost" matched cert's "secureHost"
*  issuer: C=US; ST=Arizona; L=Scottsdale; O=GoDaddy.com, Inc.; OU=http://certs.
godaddy.com/repository/; CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET Link HTTP/1.1
> Host: secureHost&Port
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.0
> Accept: */*
```

I have tried editing the default ciphers via:

```
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS += ':RC4-SHA'
```

and

```
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS += ':DES-CBC3-SHA'
```

to no avail.

Any help on making this successfull connection via the requests library is greatly appreciated.

My code so far is:

```
import requests
import json
import ssl
from urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
import MySQLdb

params = {"t": "8IBYCELFMTKRI08K5T9YUKPN7K21YZQZ0PXV"}


print(requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS)
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS += 'ALL:eNULL'

s = requests.Session()

print(requests.get('secureURL', params=params, timeout=5, verify=False).text)
```

I am using Python 2.7.13.
My installed packages are:

1. asn1crypto 0.22.0
2. certifi 2017.7.27.1
3. cffi 1.10.0
4. chardet 3.0.4
5. cryptography 2.0.3
6. enum34 1.1.6
7. idna 2.6
8. ipaddress 1.0.18
9. pyOpenSSL 17.3.0
10. pycparser 2.18
11. requests 2.18.4
12. urllib3 1.22

As far as I can tell the error is the sslv3 handshake failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I was on the network, I needed to use my VPN connection in order for the script to run. I am unsure of why this is the case, but it would not work without the VPN connection. I hope this helps someone out some day.